# Using React Dropzone together with React Final Form

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, react-final-form, react-dropzone

Trying to figure out how to use these two components together. There's [an issue on github](https://github.com/final-form/react-final-form/issues/92) that people refer to to get it up and running, but I can't figure it out. The gist of it is this:

```
<Field name={`logo`}>
  {(fieldprops) => (
    <div>
      <label>Logo</label>
      <Dropzone 
        onDrop={(files, e) => {
          props.change(`logo`, files);
          props.blur(`logo`);
        }}
      />
      <pre>{JSON.stringify(fieldprops, 0, 2)}</pre>
    </div>
  )}
</Field>
```

Using that exact code throws and error for me: `TypeError: children is not a function`

I've setup a reduced test case on [Code Sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/sweet-meitner-6yde6) that uses hooks and file preview. I also tried looking at [custom inputs](https://final-form.org/docs/react-final-form/api/Field#custom-inputs) in the docs, but seems like something is missing for it to work. Would be super happy if someone could point me in the right direction.

Comment: change `props` to`fieldprops`

Comment: @Train Thanks for the suggestion, it does throw the same error, and it's not referring to the line I initially wrote, it just throws: `TypeError: children is not a function`

Comment: your example also has a `render={...}` which you are missing

Comment: You mean that it's missing from the code in my post? It's just a short excerpt from the Code Sandbox they referred to in the issue. My point was that I took that example straight off and tried to implement, but it threw errors. The test case I link to in the bottom of the post is what I'm working with at the moment and what to get the dropzone included into the form!

Comment: I think both dropzone and final form have gone through some major rewrites since that issue was posted (beginning of 2018)

Comment: They did, and I would need to see all your code for this because it looks like your missing something. I can't really tell what your render function looks like because every `dropzone` component needs it's own render function now after `8.0` I"m not sure if that's the issue or not but if you could show more that would help.

Comment: Ok! This is really what I have https://codesandbox.io/s/sweet-meitner-6yde6 (index.js + Dropzone.js). Sorry if I'm misunderstanding what you're asking me about!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You don't have an `onChange` callback in your `Dropzone` component. How about this?

[image: Edit gracious-star-xcbzk]

Comment: Awesome, thanks! I finally found away to make it work, but it's not as clean as this, haha. Your demo has the same issue as my current implementation though. Doing a form reset won't purge the image from the preview!

Comment: An example is great but found little problem!
When we remove the image and hit submit image is still there.

Comment: this line as prop to <Dropzone  onClearForm={() => { form.change('image', undefined)}} solves the problem.